# Insert query in jasper reports

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

Is it possible to execute "insert query" in IReports/jasper reports during report generation?

Comment: What result do you want to achieve? You can try to create trigger in your calling application on pre-build report event.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the idea you need is parameters using this syntax: `$P!{PARAM_NAME}`.

So your entire SQL query (or other type of query) could be simply `$P!{SQL}`. Then you pass in exactly the dynamic SQL that you need.

UPDATE:
After reading Sharad's comment, I realized that my answer above is not good. What I wrote is true... but it fails to address the core question.

No, your report cannot really execute an insert statement. Strictly speaking, I'm sure it's not impossible. You could add a scriptlet or custom function in a .jar file that makes a connection and does an insert. But realistically speaking... a report will execute one or more queries. The JR framework is not intended to execute inserts or updates.

Comment: in our experiment, we have seen that IReport is giving error if we use insert or update...Please give us an insight on this...

Comment: @mdahlman: What I did, created a input control "$P!{p_insert_sql}" and set default value " "INSERT INTO t_error_log (LogID) VALUES(2)" but its showing error : can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery()

Comment: Don't you think if we had this facility to insert or update to database through JasperReport Server, we can do better reporting at any level, then we can use the JasperReport Server as a entry point also like excel , just create table once in database then insert the records through Jasper and see the reports, we dont have to actually use database again and again to just insert or update a record.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You can execute the query when you want to display the report. Here is a sample that works for me.

```
    try {
        Map parameters = new HashMap();
        connectionString ="jdbc:mysql://localhost/myDb", "myUsername", "myPassword"
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);
        PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        JRResultSetDataSource rsdt = new JRResultSetDataSource(rs);

        JasperPrint jp;
        jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport("sourceFileName.jasper", parameters, rsdt);
        JasperViewer jv = new JasperViewer(jp, false);
        jv.setVisible(true);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException | JRException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```