# How can we use INSERT and UPDATE statements in iReport?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

Actually I am wondering how can we use Other Data manipulation statements like INSERT and UPDATE statements inside iReport designer. I have been searching the solution for very long time but could not find anything which can actually help me.

I know even in Ireport I cant use multiple select statements separated with " ; ".

Is it possible to use these statements in Ireport?

Comment: In which situation will you use Insert or Update in IReport Designer? You can insert or update statement before Report Firing of your application...I guess...

Comment: @PiyasDe: See if we can run insert statements in ireport, means we can also insert new records through Ireport, and through UPDATE statement we can UPDATE database.

Comment: This following link may give you some insight - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712296/insert-query-in-jasper-reports Actually we did not face any situation where We had to insert or update data within IReport Designer.

Comment: What I did, created a input control "$P!{p_insert_sql}" and set default value " "INSERT INTO t_error_log (LogID) VALUES(2)" but its showing error :  can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery()

Comment: You should use executeUpdate here...

Comment: I did not get you, where i have to use  executeUpdate

Comment: So, it clearly shows you that - in IReport the API is using  executeQuery internally. executeQuery is used in java only for Select Statements. And though we can send dynamic query to ireport, we can not use Insert or update statement here.

Comment: So do I have to add executeInsert and executeupdate to execute INSERT and UPDATE statement in iReport, if yes how can I add in Ireport API?

Comment: As the IReport is using the executeQuery internally, you do not have a option to add executeUpdate within it's API. You can use Dynamic SQL for the parameter as long as it is a Select Statement.

Comment: Thanks for giving me your time but could you give me an example of Dynamic SQL in MySQL to insert a row in database?

Comment: Jav Insert into statement for mySql Statements - it may help you - http://www.roseindia.net/jdbc/jdbc-mysql/insertvalues.shtml. It is simply building a Sql and insert it through JDBC API

Comment: @Sharad What is the reason to perform *INSERT* or *UPDATE* (*DML* instructions) statements?

Comment: Don't you think if we had this facility to insert or update to database through JasperReport Server, we can do better reporting at any level, then we can use the JasperReport Server as a entry point also like excel , just create table once in database then insert the records through Jasper and see the reports, we dont have to actually use database again and again to just insert or update a record.

Answer (score 0):

IReport is for report creation only. If it can execute insert or update to database then its no longer for report. A report is something that presents meaningful data based on the user requirements. Whatever data you pass them, it can only format it, add some cosmetics, then make it printable. If you need something that inserts or updates data to the database, IReport is not what you want, but a software itself.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712296/insert-query-in-jasper-reports

Comment: I don't understand the answer given in that thread. And why would you want to insert or update the database in IReport? You might want to fire those insert/update codes before sending the report as a response.